# Intellij: Unfamiliar test status icon (horizontal dash surrounded by yellow circle)

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, integration-testing

While running integration tests of a Java app in IntellJ IDE, I noticed an unfamiliar status icon

[image: Notice the test status icon]

This icon is not listed in the [official docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/test-runner-tab.html#status).

Can someone confirm if this means that my tests passed. If yes, how are they different from the usual 'green tick' icons show up.

**UPDATE:**
I figured out that it means 'Not Started'. But not sure what it means

Comment: What does the terminal output say on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the terminated tests description here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/test-runner-tab.html

Terminated state means that test was started, but cancelled with "Stop" button.